# Stop background sound if Sound id played from react native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound

I have video player in my app, which is working fine. But there is one problem when I play the video , if there is another sound playing in the background , it keeps on playing. The ideal scenario should be that background sound should stop playing and when I pause video then background sound should start playing again. I don't know how to handle such scenarios. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you can use `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` to set how should sounds mix. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes.html) is the list for possible options. [Here](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/wiki/API#soundsetmodevalue-ios-only) and [Here](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/wiki/API#soundsetcategoryvalue-mixwithothers-ios-only) are the methods for react-native-sound for how you can set.

```
Sound.setCategory(value, mixWithOthers)
```

> value {string} Sets AVAudioSession category, which allows playing
>   sound in background, stop sound playback when phone is locked, etc.
>   Parameter options: "Ambient", "SoloAmbient", "Playback", "Record",
>   "PlayAndRecord", "AudioProcessing", "MultiRoute".

```
Sound.setMode(value)
```

> value {string} Sets AVAudioSession mode, which works in conjunction
>   with the category to determine audio mixing behavior. Parameter
>   options: "Default", "VoiceChat", "VideoChat", "GameChat",
>   "VideoRecording", "Measurement", "MoviePlayback", "SpokenAudio".
>
> This should be called in conjunction with Sound.setCategory.